# find a way to group the cells of the array X[ ] and Y[ ] into pairs that hold the same character

Tags: python

We have two arrays `X` and `Y` of `n` characters each, where `X` has `n`
randomly ordered characters, while `Y` has **exactly the same** `n` characters but **in
different order**.

Your task is to find a way to group the cells of the array `X` and `Y`
into pairs that hold the same character.
For example:
Input:

```
X = ['O', 'L', 'M', 'S', 'N', 'J', 'P', 'T', 'I', 'R', 'H', 'G']
Y = ['S', 'N', 'H', 'P', 'T', 'I', 'O', 'R', 'L', 'M', 'G', 'J']
```

Output:

```
X[0] with Y[6]
X[1] with Y[8]
X[2] with Y[9]
X[3] with Y[0]
```

… and so on

Comment: So you want to loop on array X and for each character ___find its index___ in array Y?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the characters in `x` and find their index in `y`

```
x = ["O", "L", "M", "S", "N", "J", "P", "T", "I", "R", "H", "G"]
y = ["S", "N", "H", "P", "T", "I", "O", "R", "L", "M", "G", "J"]

for i,char in enumerate(x):
    print(f"x[{i}] == y[{y.index(char)}]")
```

Or if you want to store the pairs in a list you could use this list comprehension:

```
[(i, y.index(char)) for i, char in enumerate(x)]
```